# Creating a generic utility method to make database calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two database calls in my NodeJS API that do necessarily the same thing.

```
app.get(`${BASE_URL}/users`, (req, res) => {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    connection.query('SELECT * from users', (error, results) => {
      connection.release();
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).send('Error in database operation');
      } else {
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
});

app.get(`${BASE_URL}/quizzes`, (req, res) => {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    connection.query('SELECT * from quizzes', (error, results) => {
      connection.release();
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).send('Error in database operation');
      } else {
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

What would be the best way of creating a generic method that handles the calls for both? I.e.

```
function getQuery(query) {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      connection.release();
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).send('Error in database operation');
      } else {
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

then

```
app.get(`${BASE_URL}/users`, (req, res) => {
  getQuery("SELECT * from quizzes");
});
```

Comment: no, if your going to abstract the `pool.getConnection` and `connection.query` part it shouldn't handle `res.*`, make a model which handles all users queries like `users.getAll()` etc, same with quizzes. or use something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorm so can do `await db.find('users')`, or `await db.query('SELECT * FROM users')`, and forget about the connection pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise to accomplish this:

```
function getQuery(query) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
          connection.release();
          if (error) {
            reject('Error in database operation');
          } else {
            resolve(results);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
```

The calls will look like:

```
app.get(`${BASE_URL}/users`, (req, res) => {
  getQuery('SELECT * from users')
    .then(function(results) {
      res.send(results);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

app.get(`${BASE_URL}/quizzes `, (req, res) => {
  getQuery('SELECT * from quizzes')
    .then(function(results) {
      res.send(results);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: `if (err) throw err;` is flawed.  You should be rejecting the promise.  This whole thing should be rewritten with the native promise support built into the database.  If this is mysql, then mysql2 has promise support already.

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks, i adjusted the code snippet accordingly to reject instead of throw error with the connection pool.

Comment: Not quite right yet.  `if (err) throw reject(err);` should be `if (err) return reject(err);`.  You should `return`, not `throw`.